# Can't create external table output from my hive query

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, hiveql, emr

I have a .csv file containing data about crime incidences in Philadelphia.
I am using a hive script in amazon EMR to convert this data into a HIVE table.

I am using the following hive script:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Crime(
Dc_Dist INT, 
PSA INT,
Dispatch_Date_Time TIMESTAMP,
Dispatch_Date date,
Dispatch_Time STRING, 
Hour INT,
Dc_Key BIGINT,
Location_Block STRING,
UCR_General INT,
Text_General_Code STRING,
Police_Districts INT,
Month STRING,
Lon STRING,  
Lat STRING)

COMMENT 'Data about crime from a public database'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
location 's3://dsabucket/crimeData/crime';
```

[image: This image is a screenshot of the workflow I follow to run the hive script on the AWS EMR cluster]]

I run this script but I do not get a file or data in my output folder. I am not sure if the table is created properly or not. As I understand the 'STORED AS TEXTFILE' line should store this table as a textfile.

Comment: BTW Using `IF NOT EXISTS` is dangerous in `CREATE TABLE` statement because it will silently skip statement execution if table is already exists. Use DROP+CREATE instead.

Comment: DDL will not create files. Was the data really inserted in the table? You have provided no logs. If it was, maybe there is an issue with eventual consistency.

Comment: The `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` file creates an entry in the Hive Metastore that will refer to S3 when accessing your `Crime` table. After running this command, what happens if you run `SELECT * FROM Crime" in Hive?

Answer (score 0):

to check table created or not use DESCRIBE

ie  DESCRIBE  tableNAMe;